# Documenting CMakeLists.txt and custom or local .cmake files

Tags: cmake, documentation, python-sphinx

What are good ways to document my project `CMakeLists.txt` files and local project `.cmake` files? There is a two year old question/answer [Documenting CMake scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21628833/3154588) that I am essentially asking here again. The answer contains the statement

> Currently, CMake 3.0 is under development which will get a new documentation system based on Sphinx and reStructuredText. I guess that this will bring new ways to document your modules.

I have looked at the [cmake developer documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-developer.7.html?highlight=sphinx#id2), but this *new documentation system* seems geared towards the documentation of cmake itself. I do not see how I can use this to document my user-defined project `CMakeLists.txt` files or local `.cmake` files.

I am hoping that since the cmake project internally has various sphinx directives and roles that there is was some way as a user I could take advantage of this internal usage of sphinx. I would like to be able to have some *markup* in my `CMakeLists.txt` files and local `.cmake` files without having to reinvent the wheel. There are related efforts in other projects. For example the ROS catkin project seems to offer the most complete approach that I have seen, but that is fairly heavyweight not easy to use for non-ROS projects. (As an example, look at their [extracted cmake api page](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html).) The simplest, is the [sphinx-contrib](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/) cmakedomain, but that relies on a separate rst source doc rather than an *autodoc* approach with markup comments.

Perhaps this is a question for the cmake list, but I was hoping someone was monitoring StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't think this is related to CMake, is about sphinix itself. Did you try reading a tutorial about it usage?

Comment: Yes, I know how to use sphinx. But I do not know how to use the cmake 3 *new documentation system* to document my ``CMakeLists.txt`` or other ``.cmake`` files. The cmake documentation system seems to be for documenting cmake not for users to document their project specific cmake files.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the quote, I don't think the Sphinx-related code from CMake is useful for users. I made the same experience like you, my project's CMake did not match well with the Sphinx code used in the CMake documentation.

Just use plain Sphinx and create your own templates.

Comment: I was hoping that since the cmake project internally has various sphinx directives and roles that there was some way as a user I could take advantage of them without having to reinvent the wheel. I will add this clarification to my question.

Comment: @Phil: Sure, I understood your question that way. And for my project, this did not work out. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Good news: You can use sphinx to document your CMake Modules, and at the same time use Doxygen to document your C++ (or other) source code.

I created an example project which shows how to use the `sphinxcontrib-moderncmakedomain` in combination with Sphinx and Doxygen to generate Documentation for your C++ Code AND CMake code:

https://gitlab.com/Pro1/doxygen-cmake-sphinx

It is using the `sphinxcontrib-moderncmakedomain` package and CMake itself to configure the sphinx `conf.py` and then run sphinx.

The example is heavily based on the official CMake Documentation from: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/tree/master/Utilities/Sphinx

See also the related question here:
[What is the proper way to document a CMake module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660549/what-is-the-proper-way-to-document-a-cmake-module)